# SSD not showing up after booting from usb

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, ssd, dualboot

I was trying to boot into Ubuntu live from my USB and I did, but when I restarted my pc the main SSD does not show up anymore. The name of it doesn't show in bios either and not when I go to boot menu. Any idea why booting from a USB would mess with it?

Comment: Did you install it from the Ubuntu Live USB? I noticed you have _dualboot_ in your tags.

Comment: Trying to boot into ubuntu live? As in it didn't work at first? What did you change (likely boot order in your bios, or disabled your SSD's Sata port entirely?) to make it work? Undo that change and it'll reppear.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons why a BIOS won't detect a Solid State Drive (SSD).

Make sure the drive is not disabled in the BIOS.

Setting the BIOS to the **Default** settings may help, 
then save the setting and restart the machine through BIOS.

A faulty SSD.

Any faulty or unplugged data cable(s).